# Setting input value with html code crashes the input

Tags: html

I am trying to make a web to change the data base. The problem is that some attributes from the DB are in html format, and when I try to set the input's value to the current DB attribute, it crashes.

The code that I use is the following:

```
$('#projectlist').DataTable( {
        "createdRow": function ( row, data, index ) {
            var ele = $('td', row).eq(1);
            var id_input = $('td', row).eq(0);
            id_input = id_input[0].innerHTML;
            ele[0].innerHTML = '<input id="'+id_input+'" value="'+ele[0].innerHTML+'" style="width:100%; height: 25px;">';
        },
        data: data
    } );
```

This just sets the second element from the table to be an input with the value equal to the DB.

But when the DB has html code like this one

> text \" moretext

the input finishes at the \ and following text is shown as regular text instead of input.

here's an [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B75YtBdZEpQLUVNNQWM2T0NtRFE/view?usp=sharing) of the problem. As you can see the top input is how it should be showing and the bottom input has the text that doesn't stay inside in the input box, it justs contiunes like text.

Comment: do not write content directly. Use jquerys `val` method to change the value

Answer (score 0):

like k-nut said, doing it with jquery solves the problem. If someone is interested, changing the code to this solved the problem:

```
    var ele = $('td', row).eq(1);
    var id_input = $('td', row).eq(0);
    var content=ele[0].innerHTML;
    id_input = id_input[0].innerHTML;
    ele[0].innerHTML = '<input id="'+id_input+'" style="width:100%; height: 25px;">';
    $( "#"+id_input ).val(content);
```